# Google Map V3: fitbounds and center not working together

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The following code show on a map a church and a priest:

```
    var churchLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.4, 0.14);

    var mapOptions = {
        center: churchLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('myDiv'), mapOptions);

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Setting church marker
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: churchLatLng,
        map: myMap,
    });

    bounds.extend(churchLatLng);

    var priestLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.2,0.13);                               

    new google.maps.Marker({
       position: priestLatLng, 
       map: myMap
    });

    bounds.extend(priestLatLng);    

    myMap.fitBounds(bounds);
```

The code use both the option "center" to center the church at the center of the map, and the function "fitBounds" to fit all the markers (church and priest only in this case).

The result is that the map border is set to encompass the two markers, but the option "center" doesn't work anymore and is ignored.

What I want is setting the bounds, but at the same time showing the church at the centre of the map.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think you can. `fitBounds` centres the map in the middle of all the markers that you put in the bounds. Or maybe if you do `setCenter(...)` after `fitBounds()`

Answer (score 4):

1. call myMap.fitBounds to set the bounds to show all the markers.
2. change the map to center where you like (on the church)
3. add a listener to the bounds_changed event, when that fires, check to see if the map bounds contains the priest marker, if it does, you are done.
4. if the priest marker is not contained by the map bounds, zoom out one level (map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1)).

   ```
   myMap.fitBounds(bounds);
   google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(myMap,'bounds_changed',function() {
     google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(myMap, 'center_changed', function() {
       if (!myMap.getBounds().contains(priestLatLng)) {
         myMap.setZoom(myMap.getZoom()-1);
       }
     });
     myMap.setCenter(churchLatLng);
   });
   ```

Comment: I wish there were a cleaner way to do this :/

Comment: I had to change the `center_changed` event listener to also be `addListenerOnce` instead of `addListener`, but otherwise this did exactly what I needed.

Comment: That makes sense, modified the answer to incorporate that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an eventlistener and wait for the bounds to change (it works asynchronous).
Something like:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(myMap, 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    myMap.setCenter(churchLatLng);
});
```

Comment: it centers, but the priest goes out of the map. In this way it's working only center